# Azure Dedicated SQL pool - group has db_datareader access but cannot login

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-data-warehouse, azure-synapse-analytics, dedicated-sql-pool

We have created Test AD Group and they should have readonly access to the database (schemas and tables, views) in the Azure SQL dedicated pool.

Our DBA team did it but the users in the Test AD Group cannot login until they select the database as the default database in the connection dialog in SSMS.

Is there a way to allow them to login while ONLY have readonly access to the database (including future schemas and tables that will be created)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the AD Group doesn't have permission to connect to master, which is the default database if you don't choose another database via the SSMS drop down. Try granting CONNECT to that AD Group for master. This should allow them to connect to master, not see anything, then select the database they have read-only permission to from the database drop-down.

EX (not tested):

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE USER [AD Group Name]
    FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
GO

GRANT CONNECT TO [AD Group Name]
GO
```